# amcharts stock chart class name not getting assigned

Tags: amcharts

I am working with Amcharts. I am facing an issue with adding a custom class to the bullets in AmGraph when used with Stock Charts. Here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p15saching/unm5zbg9/)

```
       bulletSize: 10,
       bulletBorderColor: "#786c56",
       bulletBorderAlpha: 1,
       bulletBorderThickness: 2,
       bulletColor: "#ff0000",
       classNameField: "className",
```

Line 90 is where I assign the classNameField to the bullets. But on-inspection the bullets do not seem to have the specified class assigned to them. The same logic works fine if i use it in simple JavaScript Charts product of Amcharts.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: The fiddle is working for me, I was able to find the `bullet1` class in the generated graph.